# How to join two data frames by 2 columns which should be matched at the same time with using inner_join, dplyr in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, inner-join

1. the goal is to match 2 long-data frames by *ID* & *year* with using `inner_join` in R

```
>data_1

ID    year    fee    health
1      0      100      1
1      1       50      2
2      0       50      2
2      1       80      3     
・
・
・
```

```
>data_2

ID    year    religion 
1      0        5
1      1        8
2      0        3
2      1        2     
・
・
・
```

the goal is like this

```
>data_join

ID    year    fee    health    religion
1      0      100      1          5
1      1       50      2          8
2      0       50      2          3
2      1       80      3          2 
・
・
・
```

I looked up the page https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html and tried to run the code below, but they could not be matched.

```
data_join <- inner_join(data_1, data_2, by = ID & year )
```

How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: try removing the ```by``` part of your code. It should work since ```inner_join``` automatically tries to join based on common columns between the two datasets

Comment: besides, the syntax for ```by``` is incorrect. If it was actually needed, you should write ```by = c('ID', 'year')```

Comment: Thank you,  Arthur Carvalho Brito, for your quick reaction. I succeeded doing that with you and  Laura M. Cruz's advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only missing the vector of the names in the variables that you want to use to connect. This should do.

data_join <- inner_join(Data_1, Data_2, by = c("ID" , "year") )

```
### Here is your example ###
    Data_1<-matrix(c(1,0,100,1,1,1,50,2,2,0,50,2,2,1,80,3), ncol=4,byrow = T)
    Data_2<-matrix(c(1,0,5,1,1,8,2,0,3,2,1,2), ncol=3,byrow = T)

    Data_1<-as.data.frame(Data_1)
    Data_2<-as.data.frame(Data_2)

    names(Data_1)<-c("ID","Year","Fee","Health")
    names(Data_2)<-c("ID","Year","Religion")

    data_join <- inner_join(Data_1, Data_2, by = c("ID" , "Year") )
```

Comment: I succeeded  it with your code! I appreciate your quick and effective advice. Thank you!